# printing a doubly linked list in reverse

Tags: c

I have a doubly linked list that I can print top to bottom, and now I'm trying to print it from bottom to top.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

//defines the struct UserData
typedef struct
{
    int importance;
    char taskName[80];
}UserData, *UserDataPtr;

//Defines a node
typedef struct node {
    UserData Data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    } Node, *NodePtr;

NodePtr makeNode(UserData);

//Declare function printList
void printList(NodePtr);

void printListRev(NodePtr);

int main()
{
   UserData info;
   NodePtr top, ptr, last, temp;



   top = NULL;

    FILE *filein=fopen("Data.txt", "r");
    if (filein == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file, exiting program.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(fscanf(filein, "%d%s",&info.importance, info.taskName)==2)
        {
            ptr=makeNode(info);
            if (top == NULL) top = ptr;
            else last -> next = ptr;
            last = ptr;
        }//end while loop

    printList(top);


    printListRev(last);
   }//end Main


//printList is a function that prints each node as long as it isn't NULL. Once it reaches NULL it terminates, signifying the end of the list.
void printList(NodePtr ptr) {
    while (ptr != NULL) { //as long as there's a node
            printf("%d %s\n", ptr -> Data.importance, ptr -> Data.taskName);
            ptr = ptr -> next; //go on to the next node

        }
    if (ptr == NULL) {

        printf("Last node data printed moving forward.\n");
    }

    } //end printList


void printListRev(NodePtr ptr) {
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%d %s\n", ptr -> Data.importance, ptr -> Data.taskName);
        ptr = ptr -> prev;


      }
    }//end printListRev

//Define function makeNode. Allocates storage for node, stores integer given to it, and returns a pointer to the new node. Also sets next field to NULL
NodePtr makeNode(UserData info) {
    NodePtr ptr = (NodePtr) malloc(sizeof (Node));
    ptr -> Data = info;
    ptr -> next = NULL;
    ptr -> prev = NULL;
    return ptr;
} //End makeNode
```

This is the output:

```
1 task1
2 task2A
3 task3A
2 task2B
4 task4A
4 task4B
3 task3B
Last node data printed moving forward.
3 task3B
```

And I have no clue why it won't print the full list in reverse. It only prints one item when printing in reverse.

Everything up until the "last node data printed" message is correct. And yes, it's a little bit messy, I'm new to C and I need to clean up my comments and such. Apologies.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should never be written with spaces around them.  (Yes, it is syntactically valid; you could put them on a separate line from the structure/pointer and member name and it would compile.  It is a question of normal or conventional presentation — the way C and C++ are written.)

Comment: During the read phase, you set `last->next` but you never set any `prev` member to anything other than NULL.  You should print the addresses (the `next` and `prev` members) with the `%p` format while printing the list forward; you'll see far too many null pointers in the `next` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the read phase, you set `last->next`, but you never set any `prev` member to anything other than `NULL`.

You can see this if you revise the `printList()` code to print the `prev` and `next` members too — using the `%p` conversion specifier.

For example:

```
void printList(NodePtr ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d %s (N = %p, P = %p)\n", ptr->Data.importance, ptr->Data.taskName,
               (void *)ptr->next, (void *)ptr->prev);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Last node data printed moving forward.\n");
    }
}
```

When run, this produces (for me, on my Mac):

```
1 task1 (N = 0x7ff6a94032e0, P = 0x0)
2 task2A (N = 0x7ff6a9403370, P = 0x0)
3 task3A (N = 0x7ff6a94033e0, P = 0x0)
2 task2B (N = 0x7ff6a9403450, P = 0x0)
4 task4A (N = 0x7ff6a94034c0, P = 0x0)
4 task4B (N = 0x7ff6a9403530, P = 0x0)
3 task3B (N = 0x0, P = 0x0)
Last node data printed moving forward.
3 task3B
```

As you can see, there is no linking in the reverse direction, so the reverse print stops after printing one element — whichever element you point to.

<sup>*Note that when you write C, you should not use spaces around either the dot `.` or arrow `->` operators.  They bind extremely tightly, and white space should not be used (for all it is syntactically legitimate).  Your code is much less readable if you use such unorthodox layout.*</sup>

The fix in the scanning code is simple:

```
    while (fscanf(filein, "%d%s", &info.importance, info.taskName) == 2)
    {
        ptr = makeNode(info);
        if (top == NULL)
            top = ptr;
        else
            last->next = ptr;
        ptr->prev = last;
        last = ptr;
    }
```

I also initialized `last = NULL;` before the loop starts; that is crucial when you use it to set the previous pointer.  You were able to omit it previously, although GCC whined about 'might be used uninitialized' with my default compilation options.  It actually wasn't used uninitialized, but the compiler (GCC 6.2.0) was understandably concerned.

With this change, the output is:

```
1 task1 (N = 0x7fa4b1602a10, P = 0x0)
2 task2A (N = 0x7fa4b1602aa0, P = 0x7fa4b16029a0)
3 task3A (N = 0x7fa4b1602b10, P = 0x7fa4b1602a10)
2 task2B (N = 0x7fa4b1602b80, P = 0x7fa4b1602aa0)
4 task4A (N = 0x7fa4b1602bf0, P = 0x7fa4b1602b10)
4 task4B (N = 0x7fa4b1602c60, P = 0x7fa4b1602b80)
3 task3B (N = 0x0, P = 0x7fa4b1602bf0)
Last node data printed moving forward.
3 task3B
4 task4B
4 task4A
2 task2B
3 task3A
2 task2A
1 task1
```

You could also print the node's address; that would make it easier to track that each of the list pointers is pointing to the right place:

```
void printList(NodePtr ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d %s (C = %p, N = %p, P = %p)\n", ptr->Data.importance, ptr->Data.taskName,
               (void *)ptr, (void *)ptr->next, (void *)ptr->prev);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("Last node data printed moving forward.\n");
}

void printListRev(NodePtr ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d %s (C = %p, N = %p, P = %p)\n", ptr->Data.importance, ptr->Data.taskName,
               (void *)ptr, (void *)ptr->next, (void *)ptr->prev);
        ptr = ptr->prev;
    }
    printf("Last node data printed moving backward.\n");
}
```

producing:

```
1 task1 (C = 0x7fd301c03270, N = 0x7fd301c032e0, P = 0x0)
2 task2A (C = 0x7fd301c032e0, N = 0x7fd301c03370, P = 0x7fd301c03270)
3 task3A (C = 0x7fd301c03370, N = 0x7fd301c033e0, P = 0x7fd301c032e0)
2 task2B (C = 0x7fd301c033e0, N = 0x7fd301c03450, P = 0x7fd301c03370)
4 task4A (C = 0x7fd301c03450, N = 0x7fd301c034c0, P = 0x7fd301c033e0)
4 task4B (C = 0x7fd301c034c0, N = 0x7fd301c03530, P = 0x7fd301c03450)
3 task3B (C = 0x7fd301c03530, N = 0x0, P = 0x7fd301c034c0)
Last node data printed moving forward.
3 task3B (C = 0x7fd301c03530, N = 0x0, P = 0x7fd301c034c0)
4 task4B (C = 0x7fd301c034c0, N = 0x7fd301c03530, P = 0x7fd301c03450)
4 task4A (C = 0x7fd301c03450, N = 0x7fd301c034c0, P = 0x7fd301c033e0)
2 task2B (C = 0x7fd301c033e0, N = 0x7fd301c03450, P = 0x7fd301c03370)
3 task3A (C = 0x7fd301c03370, N = 0x7fd301c033e0, P = 0x7fd301c032e0)
2 task2A (C = 0x7fd301c032e0, N = 0x7fd301c03370, P = 0x7fd301c03270)
1 task1 (C = 0x7fd301c03270, N = 0x7fd301c032e0, P = 0x0)
Last node data printed moving backward.
```

Comment: Your help and thorough explanations are GREATLY appreciated. I chose this as the answer because it worked and because of your explanation. I rushed to make the fixes and didn't see what you said about initializing last to NULL and I also got some funky output at the end, but upon initializing last to NULL it worked exactly as you  described.

I hope I can gain enough experience to help others as much as you have!

Answer (score 2):

When inserting nodes into the list, you forgot to set the `prev` field to appropriate value. The fix is easy: Initialize `last` to `NULL`, then set `ptr->prev = last;` after the line `ptr = makeNode(info);`

By the way, `temp` is unused.

Comment: Completely right, and your solution worked. I gave @Jonathan the answer for his explanation, but thanks for your response! Big thank you for pointing out the unused `temp` though, I forgot to delete it after trying something before(unsuccessfully lol!)

Comment: Actually I didn't notice it, the compiler did =))

Answer (score 1):

you forgot make link to `prev`.

`else last -> next = ptr;`

should be

```
else {
    ptr->prev = last;
    last -> next = ptr;
}
```

Comment: `last` initialization is not required. (Although it is a good habit)